# Deadbolt issue in Play view

Tags: playframework, deadbolt

I try to restrict (using [deadbolt](http://www.playframework.org/modules/deadbolt-1.5.1/home)) something in my view (`play! framework`) and I have to pass a parameter like:

```
#{deadbolt.restrictedResource resourceKeys:['projectEdit'], resourceParameters:['projectId':'3'}
```

You notice `3` is harcoded for example (it works). But I need it dynamic, like:

```
#{deadbolt.restrictedResource resourceKeys:['projectEdit'], resourceParameters:['projectId':${project.alias}]}
```

Well, now the code no longer works but it throws an exception:

```
 Exception raised was MissingMethodException : No signature of method: Template_1012.$() is applicable for argument types: (Template_1012$_run_closure1_closure2) values: [Template_1012$_run_closure1_closure2@370c488c] Possible solutions: _(java.lang.String), is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), get(java.lang.String).
```

Do you know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, try quote it:

```
#{deadbolt.restrictedResource resourceKeys:['projectEdit'], resourceParameters:['projectId':'${project.alias}']}
```

Let me know if that works, and we can take it from there if necessary.

Comment: Thanks but it does not work, it comes up in the code as a String: `${project.alias}`...the workaround I found is to get my project alias from the current url...

Comment: You're already in an evaluation scope, so you don't need the ${} - so try one of the following: #{deadbolt.restrictedResource resourceKeys:['projectEdit'], resourceParameters:['projectId':project.alias]} or #{deadbolt.restrictedResource resourceKeys:['projectEdit'], resourceParameters:['projectId':'' + project.alias]}